# Unbelievable, Oracle return different result for a query time to time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle query, strangely the query result are different time to time.

```
select 
cast(pmm_datetime - 1 / 24 * utc_offset as timestamp) as pmm_datetime_utc,
count(distinct(NODEB_NAME)) as num_of_recs
from pmmcounter_db.WC_B_NODEBFUNCTION_QH t1 
where pmm_datetime >= to_timestamp('201810230525','YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
and cast(pmm_datetime - 1 / 24 * utc_offset as timestamp) = '2018-10-22 19:15:00.000'
group by cast(pmm_datetime - 1 / 24 * utc_offset as timestamp)
```

Most of time, the query returned expected result as below:

```
PMM_DATETIME_UTC        NUM_OF_RECS
2018-10-22 19:15:00.000 6930
```

However, randomly, it returned the result like below. As you can see, that the same datetime and state were divided into several rows.

```
PMM_DATETIME_UTC        NUM_OF_RECS
2018-10-22 19:15:00.000 785
2018-10-22 19:15:00.000 1990
2018-10-22 19:15:00.000 162
2018-10-22 19:15:00.000 3993
```

Even more strange, I have tried to put another group by using sum for QH_NUM_OF_RECS, the result is the same.  It seems that Oracle is not able to group by PMM_DATETIME_UTC?

What's going on here? Why the query result could be different???????

Comment: is pmm_datetime a date, a timestamp, a timestamp with time zone?

Comment: @tbone pmm_datetime is TIMESTAMP(6).  Example '2018-10-23 05:00:00.000'

Comment: Note that a `timestamp(6)` could also store `2018-10-22 18:15:00.000111` or  `2018-10-22 18:15:00.000999`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, theoretically, yes. all our timestamp are rounded to 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't subtract numbers from a `TIMESTAMP` data type; this is an operation that Oracle applies to a `DATE` data type and will implicitly cast your `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` and lose precision (and then you have to apply an explicit cast to convert it back).

Instead, subtract a multiple of an `INTERVAL` (or use `NUMTODSINTERVAL( utc_offset, 'HOUR' )` to generate the interval):

```
SELECT pmm_datetime - utc_offset * INTERVAL '1' HOUR as pmm_datetime_utc,
       COUNT( DISTINCT NODEB_NAME ) as num_of_recs
FROM   pmmcounter_db.WC_B_NODEBFUNCTION_QH t1 
WHERE  pmm_datetime >= TIMESTAMP '2018-10-23 05:25:00'
AND    pmm_datetime - utc_offset * INTERVAL '1' HOUR = TIMESTAMP '2018-10-22 19:15:00.000'
GROUP BY pmm_datetime - utc_offset * INTERVAL '1' HOUR
```

You can also use a timestamp literal `TIMESTAMP '2018-10-22 19:15:00.000'` rather than relying on an implicit conversion from a string to a `TIMESTAMP` data type.

You can also use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data types to manage the conversion to UTC using `FROM_TZ` function and `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

> Why [could] the query result be different?

A `TIMESTAMP(6)` data type can contain micro-second values. If you are only interested in micro-second values then cast the value to a `TIMESTAMP(3)` to reduce the precision.

You can use:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         pmm_datetime - utc_offset * INTERVAL '1' HOUR,
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6'
       ) as pmm_datetime_utc,
       COUNT( DISTINCT NODEB_NAME ) as num_of_recs
...
```

To see if this is the case.

Comment: Great, it solved the problem. The conversion in the middle is unnecessary and problematic in this case. Do you think it is an issue on Oracle side?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code. It could solve the problem. You repeated `cast(pmm_datetime - 1 / 24 * utc_offset as timestamp)` expression in **select**, **where** and **group by** that might return different value. The reason for repeating the rows in your code is `group by`.

```
with
    cte
as
(
select 
    cast(pmm_datetime - 1 / 24 * utc_offset as timestamp)   as pmm_datetime_utc,
    NODEB_NAME                                              as num_of_recs
from
    pmmcounter_db.WC_B_NODEBFUNCTION_QH t1 
where
    pmm_datetime >= to_timestamp('201810230525','YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
)
select
    pmm_datetime_utc,
    count(distinct(NODEB_NAME)) as num_of_recs
from
    cte
where
    pmm_datetime_utc = '2018-10-22 19:15:00.000'
group by
    pmm_datetime_utc;
```

Comment: Why would this make any difference? `utc_offset` appears to be a constant (with regards to a single execution of the query) and `pmm_datetime` is a `TIMESTAMP(6)` value stored in a column and neither will vary during the execution of the different parts of the query.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, the query you suggested failed with ORA-00979. Not a Group by expression.:)

Comment: @user3893836 you are right. so sorry, there were some error on the query. I updated the answer.

Comment: @MT0 `group by` is the only clause that makes change in this query result-set. I mean there are some different value for column `pmm_datetime_utc` that made changes.